# Passing values to JMeter script at run time through bat file

Tags: batch-file, jmeter, parameter-passing, jmeter-3.2

I need to pass thread group, ramp up time and loop count to a JMeter script at run-time after getting the inputs from the user.

For this I have created a bat file like below:

```
@echo off
title Accepting User Inputs And Passing It To JMeter Scripts !!
echo Welcome To The World Of Performance Testing !!

set /p thread=Enter the count for thread groups: 
set /p rampup=Enter the ramp up peroid: 
set /p loopcount=Enter the loopcount:

set /p cd = "E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin"

%cd%\jmeter -n -t E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\scripts\SampleTestPlan.jmx -l 
E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\results\result1.csv -JThread=%thread% - 
JRampUp=%rampup% -JLoopCount=%loopcount%

pause
```

But I'm getting the output as below, it's accepting the inputs but I'm unable to launch the command to run Jmeter in non-GUI mode by redirecting to location - **E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin** using the .bat file.

[image]

Comment: `cd` is reserved for current directory, so you use `%cd%`, which is not the same as `%cd %` that you set using `set /p cd = ...`. The space before `=` can be included as part of the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to directory of jmeter in script:

```
 E:
 cd E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin
 jmeter -n -t E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\scripts\SampleTestPlan.jmx -l 
   E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\results\result1.csv -JThread=%thread% - 
   JRampUp=%rampup% -JLoopCount=%loopcount%
```

Comment: Perfect - tried with the same thing meanwhile and it worked, anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your script in another (i.e. "fresh") [terminal window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), your script looks more or less good, it might be the case you have `%cd%` variable defined somewhere else and it overrides the setting from the batch script.

---

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever is the most recent version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) as soon as possible

Comment: How can I run my script in different terminal, currently I am just double-clicking on the bat file.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `Start`'s options too!

```bat
@Echo Off
Title Accepting user inputs and passing them to a JMeter Script
Echo Welcome To The World Of Performance Testing.
Set /P "thread=Enter the count for thread groups: "
Set /P "rampup=Enter the ramp up peroid: "
Set /P "loopcount=Enter the loopcount: "
Set "jmdir=E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin"
Start "" /B /D "%jmdir%" /Wait jmeter -n -t scripts\SampleTestPlan.jmx -l results\result1.csv -JThread=%thread% -JRampUp=%rampup% -JLoopCount=%loopcount%
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

@user7294900 - Have used below thing in my batch file -

```
e:
cd apache-jmeter-3.2\bin

jmeter -n -t E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\scripts\SampleTestPlan.jmx -l E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\results\results1.csv -JThreads=%thread% -JRampUp=%rampup% -JLoopCount=%loopcount%

pause
```